# Better HTML/Razor Formatting in VS 2010 (one Attribute per Line)?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, formatting

Does anyone know how i can get better formatting for Razor/HTML (with CTRL K+D or another Shortcut) ?

I want it to be nicely intended, every tag be in a new line, every attribute inside a tag should also get a new line.

Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> HTML does not give these options no matter how configure it.
I also could not find an extension to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Code_Style_Configuration_and_Sharing) has some nice options for organising your code

EDIT: although it looks like there isn't a lot of support for HTML formatting more for the C#/VB code side of things